# random PHP file includes in Laravel (blade template)

Tags: php, laravel, include, laravel-blade

normally with PHP this would be as easy as:

1. reading the list of files into and array from disk
2. then using the `array_rand` function to select any one file randomly
3. then I could include it using the `include` statement

However I am not able to emulate the same behavior in Laravel within a blade template using just pure PHP, what am I missing here?

Comment: It seems to me that something like this should not be done in a template anyway. Choosing a random include file should be done before the template is loaded, and then passed to the template as a variable, or even as a separate parsed view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this. Not optimal or anything but works well.

resources/views/includes/random.blade.php

```
<?php      
$winners = array(
      '<div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/QabnXJC07AM?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <h3>RANDOM1</h3>
        <p class="lead">By <b>RANDOM1</b>
          <br>
          <br> from <b><small>sadasdasd,asdasdasd,asdasdasd</small></b>
        </p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p><b><i class="fa fa-5x fa-trophy" style="color:#FFD700; text-shadow: 2px 1px 1px #ccc;"></i> <span style="font-size: 2.5em;">5<sup>th</sup></span> eYRTC-2014</b>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>',
      '<div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/z5Srn_AQk_U?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <h3>Care RANDOM2</h3>
        <p class="lead">By <b>RANDOM2</b>
          <br>
          <br> from <b><small>sfasdfaffd,fasdfdaf,adsfafafafd,afds</small></b>
        </p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p><b><i class="fa fa-5x fa-trophy" style="color:#FFD700; text-shadow: 2px 1px 1px #ccc;"></i> <span style="font-size: 2.5em;">6<sup>th</sup></span> eYRTC-2014</b>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>'
      );
      $random_keys=array_rand($winners,1);
      echo $winners[$random_keys];    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a random file to include is application logic, so it should stay well out of your views.

In your controller (not necessarily the best place, depends on size of application etc.):

```
$views = [
    'random1',
    'random2',
    'random3'
];

return View::make('main', [
    'random' => View::make($views[mt_rand(0, count($views) - 1)])
]);
```

In your blade template:

```
{{ $random }}
```

Note: this is for Laravel 4